# Что такое index_name и CONSTRAINT [symbol]

Tags: mysql

В [документации MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) предоставлен вот такой шаблон:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```

Вопросы следующие:

1. Что означает CONSTRAINT [symbol] и в каких случаях используется?
2. Что означает [index_name] и в каких случаях используется?

Comment: Про index_name по Вашей же ссылке буквально строчкой ниже написано _"index_name represents a foreign key ID"_.

Comment: @Yaant Я видел эту строчку, но она была мне непонятна на момент составления этого вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CONSTRAINT - название вашего ограничения. В данном случае, это имя для внешнего ключа. Пригодится, если вы, к примеру, захотите удалить это ограничение. Без указания имени система автоматически назначит имя.
2. Это наименование индекса. Если не задавать, имя будет сгенерировано системой. Используется для быстрого извлечения данных. Выборка по первичным и внешним ключам быстрая за счёт этих индексов. Про индексы можно почитать [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё теперь стало более понятным.
Получается, чтобы удалить ограничение нужно использовать его название. Есть ли какое-нибудь общеепринятое правило о составлении имени для ограничения? И какой шаблон использует  MySQL при автоматическом назначении имени (я не смог найти это в документации самостоятельно)

Comment: @JohnKent по поводу общепринятых правил не скажу, я с sql базами давно не работал. Имена там из разряда `FK__B__B_COL1__111111111` генерируются. Где числовая часть как-то зависит от B-tree у индекса. Тут нет какой-то закономерности, как мне кажется. Если нужно будет использовать имя для индекса или ограничения, то лучше задавайте сами.